# ¿Cuáles palabras serían iguales a "favela?"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, colombia, argentina

Quisiera saber si hay algunos términos universales o si hay términos usados en diferentes países para referirse a lo equivale a una favela brasileña pero en territorio de un país hispanohablante, como por ejemplo en Colombia.

He visto en un libro escrito por un autor Colombiano que usa el termino «barriada» pero realmente no sé si ésta sería igual a una favela o algo peor. Me parece que hay diferentes niveles de la pobreza y algunos sectores aunque sean pobres son muchos mejores que otros.

Mas comúnmente he escuchado la gente usar simplemente el término «barrio popular» o aún más simplemente «barrio». Eso me ha causado más confusión porque no sé si en Colombia siempre implica «barrio popular» o «barrio pobre» si dices «barrio».

Y (en Colombia en particular), ¿«barrio popular» sí es equivalente a «barrio pobre»?

Entonces ¿qué es una «barriada?» ¿Y un «tugurio» es aún peor?

¿Cuáles términos ya no se usan? Por ejemplo, en las canciones de Gardel escucho de arrabales pero hoy en día solo escucho de las villas. ¿Hay «arrabales» en algún lado aún?

Comment: https://catcomm.org/latin-america-map/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El equivalente a *favela* en Colombia sería **«barrio popular»**

*«Barrio»* por si solo es una de las formas como se dividen las ciudades. Por ejemplo mi ciudad Medellín está dividida en 16 secciones grandes que llamamos «comunas» pero también está conformada por 275 barrios, obviamente no todos ricos ni todos pobres.

**Barrio pobre** es un poco despectivo por lo que no es la forma común y se prefiere usar **barrio popular**, refiriéndose a un barrio en el que la mayoría de sus habitantes tiene ingresos mínimos y pertenecen a la clase obrera de la ciudad

La palabra **barriada** se refiere más a la gente que al lugar. Es una manera poco común de hablar de los *habitantes de un barrio*

**Tugurio** no tiene nada que ver con barrio. Un «tugurio» es una construcción hecha con cartones, latas y material de reciclaje, que obviamente, es construida por una persona/familia muy pobre, pero los *barrios pobres* no están hechos de tugurios.

Siempre se asocia *favela* con extrema pobreza, construcciones irregulares y delincuencia, pero también existen *favelas* con un nivel de vida aceptable, donde habitan personas de ingresos medios o algo superiores al ingreso mínimo. De igual forma en Colombia algunos *barrios populares* son simplemente habitados por la clase obrera mientras que en otros si hay extrema pobreza, construcciones irregulares (incluyendo tugurios) y delincuencia.

Answer (score 4):

Una posibilidad es denominarlos "barrios marginales". Otra posibilidad es "barrios de chabolas":

> En España se denomina informalmente chabola a los barrios bajos, un tipo de asentamiento humano marginal, poco salubre y frecuentemente formado por personas excluidas socialmente. Su término en castellano es Asentamiento informal. Otros nombres locales en castellano son: zona marginal, villa miseria, población callampa, cantegriles, favelas, barrios jóvenes, cinturones de miseria, asentamientos humanos y más.
>
> [Chabolismo en wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chabolismo)

De acuerdo a la RAE el [chabolismo](https://dle.rae.es/chabolismo?m=form) es

> 1. m. Abundancia de chabolas en los suburbios de las grandes ciudades.

y por supuesto una [chabola](https://dle.rae.es/chabola) (o chavola) es

> Vivienda de escasas proporciones y pobre construcción, que suele edificarse en zonas suburbanas.

Comment: ¿En España hay lugares así?

Comment: @aris [se están intentando eliminar](https://www.elindependiente.com/economia/2018/10/06/chabolismo-madrid-los-otros-mini-gallineros/), pero [sigue habiendo](https://www.abc.es/espana/madrid/abci-chabolismo-multiplica-leganes-201903030047_noticia.html).

Answer (score 2):

Barrio en Colombia denota un sector de casas sean populares o de clase alta. El adjetivo [tugurial](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tugurial), vale para describir que un barrio es de clase baja (sin ser la palabra que más se usa). Si bien suele usarse más para unos pocos sectores, donde suelen vivir habitantes de la calle o vendedores de estupefacientes, la palabra [olla](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=olla) suele usarse en las [grandes ciudades](https://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-16615127) (3er. párrafo) de Colombia a nivel popular.

Comment: Creo importante aclarar que una *olla* no es un barrio. Una *olla* es un sector generalmente de una o dos calles, tomado por la delincuencia para el desarrollo de actividades criminales.